# iOS: reversible hash for NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'd like to 'hash' a string on iOS with my own custom key; important is to do the opposite as well, e.g.

```
NSString *secretWord = @"Hello World!";

secretWord = [self hashWithKey:@"customKey"];

// secret Word is now something unreadable, like 'kjwlekjfoaijfoijwef'

NSLog(@"%@", [secretWord unhashWithKey:@"customKey"]); // prints 'Hello World!'
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Encryption is the solution you are looking for, hashing is only one-way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hashing (which is one-way), but encryption you're asking for.

You can use RNCryptor for this purpose: https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor

If the (binary) result seems unreadable to you and you need something human-readable, try Base64-encoding it.